# Import poorly formatted CSV/JSON to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, import, json

I am trying to parse Android notification logs into a database. The columns are uneven because different notifications omit certain attributes. Essentially, it is a CSV file of key-value pairs. To put it another way, it is a really poorly formatted (& syntactically incorrect) JSON file. Maybe it would be easier to show you...

```json
{"packageName":"com.automatic.mustang","postTime":1489795785973,"systemTime":1489795786083,"offset":-14400000,"isOngoing":false}
{"packageName":"com.enhance.gameservice","postTime":1489040766066,"systemTime":1489040766136,"offset":-18000000,"isOngoing":false}
{"packageName":"com.automatic.mustang","postTime":1489795785973,"systemTime":1489795786083,"offset":-14400000,"isOngoing":false}
{"packageName":"com.enhance.gameservice","postTime":1489040766066,"systemTime":1489040766136,"offset":-18000000,"isOngoing":false}
```

**I have truncated them for the sake of brevity, but they do not line up toward the end of the rows.** Some text values are quoted, some are not. *All of the keys are quoted.* I can use string functions to trim the extraneous characters once I get the columns sorted, but therein lies the rub: How do I sort the values into columns? I can do this in about 4 different programming languages, but I am just learning T-SQL.

**How can I parse this to SQL Server (2016) in a single query? Is it even possible?**

I could import it to a temporary table & then transfer it to the permanent one, but I would like to have one query to digest the info, since this will be repeated on a daily (maybe more) basis. The magic would be if I could declare a second-level delimiter, since all values are preceded by a colon. Declaring the colon as the delimiter breaks it the other way...arg(s)!

The data is all around ragged. Even the notifications from the same app may be drastically different. The way I would do it in PHP, C, JS, etc  would be to loop through the keys until I hit the ones I needed, grab the appropriate values following them (or the whole pair), then trim the extraneous chars. I just don't know how to do it in T-SQL & the online docs leave something to be desired.

The expected result would be something like this:

```
Package Name | Post Time | System Time | Offset | NotificationText
-----------------------------------------------------------------
automatic    | 1489795   | 786083      | -1400  | this is the note
gameservice  | 1489756   | 786090      | -1400  | this is the note
automatic    | 1489799   | 786045      | -1400  | this is the note
```

The big problem is that the info I need is scattered throughout the rows. I don't need much of it, but it is buried.

Comment: Yeah, don't do that with T-SQL. Process your text files and import the cleaned versions.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik Not possible, or prohibitively complicated? The goal is to eliminate steps from the workflow. I can code things that are complicated, I just don't know T-SQL very intimately, & I can't seem to figure out the conditional logic & string matching functions. Thanks for the help all the same though! I totally appreciate it.

Comment: I think what @sp_BlitzErik is trying to say is that SQL Server is a ridiculously expensive way to do row-by-row string parsing. Best practice is to do the parsing in a procedural language before you insert it into the database table(s) and leave the database server to do database stuff, like storage, sorting, aggregating.

Comment: Hahaha, I fell asleep before I could respond last night. But yeah, @DanielHutmacher is right. I've tried to do stuff like this early on in my T-SQL days as well, and it was so bad I resorted to doing it with PowerShell instead. PowerShell! That's how bad it was.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the technique shown in [Loading line-delimited JSON files in SQL Server 2016](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/03/23/loading-line-delimited-json-files-in-sql-server-2016/) on the SQL Server Database Engine Blog, written by Jovan Popovic .

For example, given a file `import.txt`:

```
{"packageName":"com.automatic.mustang","postTime":1489795785973,"systemTime":1489795786083,"offset":-14400000,"isOngoing":false}
{"packageName":"com.enhance.gameservice","postTime":1489040766066,"systemTime":1489040766136,"offset":-18000000,"isOngoing":false}
{"packageName":"com.automatic.mustang","postTime":1489795785973,"systemTime":1489795786083,"offset":-14400000,"isOngoing":false}
{"packageName":"com.enhance.gameservice","postTime":1489040766066,"systemTime":1489040766136,"offset":-18000000,"isOngoing":false}
```

and a format file `import.fmt`:

```
13.0
1
1 SQLCHAR 0 0 "\r\n" 1 json ""
```

The file can be bulk imported and parsed with:

```
SELECT
    Parsed.packageName,
    Parsed.postTime,
    Parsed.systemTime,
    Parsed.offset,
    Parsed.isOngoing
FROM OPENROWSET
(
    BULK 'C:\Temp\import.txt',
    FORMATFILE= 'C:\Temp\import.fmt'
) AS BulkLog
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(BulkLog.[json])
WITH
(
    packageName varchar(50),
    postTime    bigint,
    systemTime  bigint,
    offset      bigint,
    isOngoing   bit
) AS Parsed;
```

Giving:

[image: Parsed results]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you think this is syntactically incorrect JSON, but according to [json.org](http://www.json.org/), it looks fine. Well, except for 2 minor things:

1. need commas between sets of `{` and `}`
2. Need `[` and `]` around the entire thing

But outside of that, it is supposed to be that all keys are quoted, and that numbers and booleans values are *not* quoted.

SQL Server 2016 has built-in JSON parsing. After fixing those two minor issues with the sample data in the question, the below parses it just fine:

```
DECLARE @JSON NVARCHAR(MAX) =N'
[{"packageName":"com.automatic.mustang","postTime":1489795785973,"systemTime":1489795786083,"offset":-14400000,"isOngoing":false},
{"packageName":"com.enhance.gameservice","postTime":1489040766066,"systemTime":1489040766136,"offset":-18000000,"isOngoing":false},
{"packageName":"com.automatic.mustang","postTime":1489795785973,"systemTime":1489795786083,"offset":-14400000,"isOngoing":false},
{"packageName":"com.enhance.gameservice","postTime":1489040766066,"systemTime":1489040766136,"offset":-18000000,"isOngoing":false}]
';

   SELECT [PackageName],
          [IsOngoing]
   FROM   OPENJSON(@JSON)
   WITH (
      [PackageName] VARCHAR(MAX)       '$.packageName',
      [IsOngoing]   BIT                '$.isOngoing'
   );
```

Returns:

```
PackageName                IsOngoing
com.automatic.mustang      0
com.enhance.gameservice    0
com.automatic.mustang      0
com.enhance.gameservice    0
```

Answer (score 0):

This format is called [JSON lines](https://jsonlines.org) and is the JSON format used by several tools such as [Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-json.html) and [spyql](https://github.com/dcmoura/spyql).

I suggest using spyql to generate `INSERT` statements that you should be able to import to any sql database:

```
$ spyql -Otable=my_table "SELECT json->packageName, json->postTime, json->systemTime, json->offset, json->isOngoing FROM json TO sql" < my_file.json 
INSERT INTO "my_table"("packageName","postTime","systemTime","offset","isOngoing") VALUES ('com.automatic.mustang',1489795785973,1489795786083,-14400000,False),('com.enhance.gameservice',1489040766066,1489040766136,-18000000,False),('com.automatic.mustang',1489795785973,1489795786083,-14400000,False),('com.enhance.gameservice',1489040766066,1489040766136,-18000000,False);
```

You would have to previously create the table in your database, but that's it.

Disclosure: I am the author of spyql.